# asprintf(); causing memory issues

Tags: c, memory

I'm using `asprintf(&somestring,"%s%s",stringone,stringtwo)` to concatenate strings. It works fine if I call it once and then `free(somestring)` once. However, I run into problems if I call `asprintf()` multiple times but only `free(somestring)` once in a recursive function. Does `free()` need to be called for every `asprintf()`?

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>Does `free()` need to be called for every `asprintf()`?</sub>

Yes. As per its [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

> The functions `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are analogs of `sprintf(3)` and `vsprintf(3)`, except that *they allocate a string* large enough to hold the output including the terminating null byte, *and return a pointer to it* via the first argument. ***This pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.***

Comment: but in a recursive function, how would I free the string multiple times?

Comment: If you pass the result of `asprintf()` to another function to use, you free the pointer when that function is done with it. A recursive call isn't any different.